# How do I determine the latest date of a transaction restored to a database on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am log shipping between two SQL Server 2008 servers.  This is our own log shipping and not the built in (we have 500+ databases and it is easier this way).  I want simple monitoring to make sure the fail-over site has the latest transaction logs.

How can I tell the latest transaction log that was restored to a database?

Can I tell the date/time that the log was backed up from the source server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine keeps a history of all backup operations in MSDB tables. See [Viewing Information About Backups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188653.aspx). Eg. the [`backupset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186299.aspx) table will contain

> a row for each backup set. A backup
>   set contains the backup from a single,
>   successful backup operation.

You can get the LSN and date of the last backup of each DB from there. Then you can look on your destination MSDBs and inspect the [`restorehistory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187408.aspx) table which contains one row for each restore operation and you can see when was last restore applied.